# HTML use script only in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I need to use a script only in Internet Explorer and for this I use the following line of code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
        if(/MSIE \d|Trident.*rv:/.test(navigator.userAgent))
            document.write('<script src="js/jszip-utils-ie.min.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

The problem is that it works when I execute it locally, but when uploading it to the server it does not detect if I am in Internet Explorer and it does not execute this script. Any idea what the reason may be? Thank you!

Comment: Can you detail what do you mean "does not execute the script"? Please edit your post.

Comment: What does the browser console say, and what have you done so far to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should check what kind of version of IE you’ve used.

You have to check **the version you've used locally** and **the version of the server**.

```
 <!--[if IE]>xxxxx<![endif]-->
```

The conditional comments are not supported in all versions.

For IE10 and other browsers, this may not work.

For more about conditional comments, you could refer to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh801214(v=vs.94)